# What is the best way to redirect (301) many articles on Gatsby JS?

Tags: .htaccess, gatsby, http-redirect

I'm migrating a Wordpress blog to Gatsby.

I need to create redirections (http 301) from this kind of url :

`https://myblog.com/my-article-slug`

To this kind of url

`https://myblog.com/blog/my-article-slug`

I found two plugins that could help me to do it but it seems tedious to use them since I have 50+ articles.

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-htaccess/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-redirect-from/

FYI :
This website has internal pages like `/contact` or `/terms` so I can't just redirect anything from `/slug` to `/blog/slug`.

Do you have any better way to do this in mind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Netlify you can try using a _redirects file : https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/